Monte Carlo Simulation for Feynman path integral
I am trying to implement a Monte Carlo algorithm to plot the trajectories and the corresponding (position) expectation value of these trajectories in the Feynman path integral formalism for a harmonic oscillator. For that I am using Matlab. I am not especially good when it comes to programming and it's also my first time I am using a Monte Carlo algorithm, so maybe my question is trivial for some: When I run my code 2 times, shouldn't the expectation value be the same? I know that the trajecties will look different in each run, but my guess is that the expectation value is the same every run if I use a big enough sample size (here 10.000). I also tried this with 1000.000 as sample size and it still wasn't the case. I will append 2 images, which are made with a sample size of 10.000, the coloured lines are the position trajectories in time for each sample and the blue line is the expectation value of the position. Can someone tell me, if I have a misunderstanding? Or maybe someone immediately sees an obvious error in my code. Thank you!
clear all;
% Initialize constants
dt = 1;  %Time step
Ntau = floor(120 / dt); % Number of time slices, floor rounds down to integer
m = 1*dt;
omega = 1*dt;
idrate = 0.8;
h = 0.1; % Step size
N = 10000; % Number of samples
Nsep = 12; % Separation between samples

% Harmonic potential function
V_Harm = @(lambda, x) 0.5 * m * (omega^2) * (x.^2);

% Monte Carlo sweep function
function [path, h] = MC_sweep(path, Ntau, h, V, m, idrate)
    % Perform a Monte Carlo sweep on a 1D path using the Metropolis algorithm
    % Inputs:
    %   path - Current path configuration
    %   Ntau - Number of time slices (size of the path)
    %   h - Current step size
    %   V - Potential function handle
    %   m - Mass parameter
    %   idrate - Target acceptance rate
    
    accept_rate = 0; % Initialize acceptance rate counter
    indices = randperm(Ntau); % Randomly shuffle indices for the sweep
    
    for i = 1:Ntau
        % Select a random site based on shuffled indices
        t = indices(i);
        tmin = mod(t - 2 + Ntau, Ntau) + 1; % Previous index (periodic boundary)
        tplu = mod(t, Ntau) + 1;           % Next index (periodic boundary)
        
        % Propose a new configuration
        x_new = path(t) + h * (rand - 0.5); % Random displacement
        
        % Compute the old and new actions
        S_old = 0.5 * m * ((path(tplu) - path(t))^2 + (path(tmin) - path(t))^2) ...
                + V(0, path(t)); % Use potential V
        S_new = 0.5 * m * ((path(tplu) - x_new)^2 + (path(tmin) - x_new)^2) ...
                + V(0, x_new);
        
        % Metropolis criterion
        if rand < exp(- (S_new - S_old))
            % Accept the new configuration
            path(t) = x_new;
            accept_rate = accept_rate + 1 / Ntau; % Increment acceptance rate
        end
    end
    
    % Adjust the step size `h` based on acceptance rate
    h = h * (accept_rate / idrate);
end

% Initialize paths
path0 = zeros(1, Ntau);
path = path0;
path_arr = {path};

% Thermalize path
for i = 1:200
    [path, h] = MC_sweep(path, Ntau, h, V_Harm, m, idrate);
    path_arr{end + 1} = path; % Append path to array
end

thermalized_path = path;

% Collect samples
path_arr = cell(1, N);
for i = 1:N
    path = thermalized_path;
    for j = 1:Nsep
        [path, h] = MC_sweep(path, Ntau, h, V_Harm, m, idrate);
    end
    path_arr{i} = path;
end

% x trajectories 
x_t_values_array = {};
for t = 1:Ntau
    x_t_values = cellfun(@(p) p(t), path_arr);
    x_t_values_array{end+1} = x_t_values;
end

% x expectation value
expectation_x_t = cellfun(@(x) mean(x,'all'),x_t_values_array);
x_t_values_matrix = vertcat(x_t_values_array{:});

%Number of time slices
time_steps = 1:Ntau;

figure
hold on;
for i=1:N
    plot(time_steps, x_t_values_matrix(:,i))
end
hold on
plot(time_steps , expectation_x_t, 'b','LineWidth',1.5)
hold off




Are you trying to simulate an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process or a genuine quantum harmonic oscillator ?

Maybe someone immediately sees an obvious error in my code. We don’t review code. Implementation details of computational tasks are off-topic on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

When I run my code 2 times, shouldn't the expectation value be the same? That could depend on whether you seeded the random number generator to produce the same sequence of “random” numbers on each run.

@Ghoster Thank you for the information, I wasn't aware. Regarding the expectation value, the path x is randomly changed in the Metropolis step without any seed which could reproduce this random change. But nontheless I think that the graphs of the expectation value should be the same, because the trajectories while random, are averaged over 10.000 samples. Also just intuitively any expectation value should always be the same if I consider the same system or not?

@LPZ Hi, I am trying to simulate a quantum harmonic oscillator using Feynmans path integral.
